# How can i check if the table mysql.proc exists

Tags: mysql

I am working on a WPF application which installs if MySQL is installed,
so before installation I want to check whether `mysql.proc` table exists or not.
I googled about it and ended up with a query

```
select * from information_schema.Tables 
   where Table_schema = Schema() and Table_Name = 'mysql.proc'
```

This query returns an empty row.

I also tried simple select statement
`select * from mysql.proc`,
and this returned a table with the names of all the stored procedures, but if this table didn't exists then it throws an exception in the c# code.

So is there any way that I can fire a query from c# and get a boolean value depending on whether `mysql.proc` table exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SHOW TABLES FROM mysql LIKE 'proc'`. If there are no result rows, the table doesn't exist. If there is one row, the table exists. Note that this approach isn't portable across RDBMSs, though that doesn't seem to be a concern of yours.

As for your first query, [`SCHEMA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_database) returns the default database, so if it's not "mysql", the query will fail. Likewise, data in the `Table_Name` column doesn't include the database name, so comparing to 'mysql.proc' will always fail.